# Apropos para o PowerShell

Tags: powershell, unix, portabilidade

No Windows há alguma solução em PowerShell que possa apresentar algum resultado de pesquisa de comandos semalhante ao [apropos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apropos_(Unix)) do Unix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function apropos {
    $glob = $args[0]
    (gcm $glob).FileVersionInfo|
        select FileName,FileDescription
}
```

Agora no console do PS apenas digite:

```
apropos *cmd*

FileName                            FileDescription                                            
--------                            ---------------                                            
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe         Processador de comandos do Windows                         
C:\Windows\system32\cmdkey.exe      Utilitário gerenciador de credenciais da linha de comando  
C:\Windows\system32\cmdl32.exe      Download automático do Gerenciador de Conexões da Microsoft
C:\Windows\system32\hkcmd.exe       hkcmd Module                                               
C:\Windows\system32\onlinesetup.cmd                                                            
C:\Windows\system32\VaultCmd.exe    Programa cmdline do Cofre                                  
C:\Windows\system32\winrm.cmd
```